# PHP Scraping images from bing with panther library show chrome port 9515 already in use

Tags: php, web-scraping, symfony-panther

I am trying to to scrape images from a rss feed by passing the first 3 words i am searching on bing for images and trying to **scrape** the images. My code is working but i always get the error that port 9515 is already in use. I have already added code to kill the port but its not working please help me out. I took reference from this url to build my code `https://www.thoughtfulcode.com/php-web-scraping/`./ Please help me out.

**Code**

```
 include ('vendor/autoload.php');
    
 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

 $url="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeedstopstories.cms";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
 $array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
 $description=array();
 $i_size=sizeof($array['channel']['item'])-1;
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array['channel']['item']);$i++){
      $title=$array['channel']['item'][$i]['title'];
      $keyword_array=explode(" ",$title);
      $keyword=$keyword_array[0].' '.$keyword_array[1].' '.$keyword_array[2];
      download_feed_image($keyword);
      if($i_size==$i){
       echo "done";
    }
 }


    function download_feed_image($keyword){
       try {
          $client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient();
          $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.bing.com/images/search?q='.$keyword.'&form=HDRSC2&first=1&cw=1349&ch=657');
          $fullPageHtml = $crawler->html();
          $pageH1 = $crawler->filter('.iusc')->attr('href');
          $img_tag=null;
          parse_str($pageH1,$img_tag);
          $file_name = basename($img_tag['mediaurl']);
          file_put_contents( $file_name,file_get_contents($img_tag['mediaurl']));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        } finally {
            $client->quit();
        }
        exec("kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:9515)");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just restart computer help to kill Chrome browser instance or
if you use Ubuntu type in terminal `pkill chrome`

```
$client->quit();
```

Not works when Browser is busy and not answered :(
Before you quit from Chrome browser you need to delete temporary data

```
$client->close();
$client->quit();
```

P.s. You can see Chrome browser status here
http://127.0.0.1:9515/status